# How do I use IIS ReWrite redirect from server name to fully qualified domain name

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have an internal domain iis server which has a website that is bound to https

sitename
and
sitename.domain.com

but it also accepts http to

sitename
and
sitename.domain.com

I want to redirect using iis url rewrite so when someone enters
http://sitename/?foo=bar
it redirects to
https://sitename.domain.com/?foo=bar

I also want to redirect url
https://sitename/?foo=bar
to
https://sitename.domain.com/?foo=bar

I have not been able to get this working at all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500 (internal server error)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sitename$" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://sitename.domain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```